# Need to Hide Menu Button in Action Bar Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to customize my action bar in android. I have created a custom layout like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/actionBarTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sample"/>    
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/actionBarImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/some_image"/>
```

and my code is:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    // Do any other config to the action bar
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_layout);
```

I am able to see my custom layout in the action bar but along with that I get the menu icon at the extreme right of the action bar. I dont know how to remove or hide it.Pls help me out.

Comment: Did you also inflate `menu.xml`? The icon on the rightmost is an overflow button used for device without physical menu button.

Comment: yes. I am inflating menu.xml. Now I have tried without inflating menu.xml. It works now. Thanks a lot. @Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I get the menu icon at the extreme right of the action bar

Either:

- You have defined items to appear in the overflow area, in which case, get rid of those, or
- Your `android:targetSdkVersion` is under 11, in which case, raise it

See: [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).